# What does it mean to have an unknown key in my `gpg --list-keys`

Tags: gnupg

I have just set up GPG for the first time. When I do `gpg --list-keys` I see a key other than my own (which is also there) about which I have no idea how it got there, what does this mean? (I don't even know what the keys listed here are for, how they can get there, what it allows, etc.)

Comment: Can you provide the actual output? You can remove names and keyids for privacy.